# The [quality] tag adds no quality to SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

> Quality is a generic term mostly used for image and video clarity and quality.

Really, [quality](/questions/tagged/quality) tag wiki excerpt?  Really really?

Of the **364** questions, about a hundred seem to be about various image API quality settings and/or are whining about image quality.  While there's nothing wrong with that, the tag chosen to represent this concept is horrifyingly horrible.

While [image-quality](/questions/tagged/image-quality) and [videoquality](/questions/tagged/videoquality) exist, we need to ask ourselves if it's worth switching to these tags.  They're kinda ... generic.  Meta, if you will.

Then there's the 75-ish that are paired with [testing](/questions/tagged/testing) (*oh no, a gerund!*), [qa](/questions/tagged/qa), [software-quality](/questions/tagged/software-quality), and other similar tags.

This tag needs a cleanup, and then probably a burnination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I'll tell you what's *not* in the box...

The [quality](/questions/tagged/quality) tag.  Burned.

Comment: In all the years of interneting, I can now truly say:  you owe me a new keyboard.